# Add new css class to dynamically generated images and div in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm creating some dynamic images and divs in jquery.

```
user = wrapper.append("<div class='user-container' />"); 
user.append("<img class='user-img' src='" + path + "'/>;
```

How do I apply the classes user-img and user-container using my external css?

Thanks,
Ansh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The append method returns the current jQuery object itself and not the appended element object.

You can define the HTML content and other attributes by wrapping the div HTML using jQuery.

```
wrapper.append($("<div/>",{
  html : "<img class='user-img' src='" + path + "'/>",
  class : 'user-container'
}));
```

---

Or you can do it in a reverse manner to keep the reference of appended element using `appendTo()` method in jQuery.

```
var wrapper = $("<div class='wrapper'></div>").appendTo("main"); 
var user = $("<div class='user-container' />").appendTo(wrapper); 
user.append("<img class='user-img' src='" + path + "'/>");
```

Comment: var wrapper = $("main").append("<div class='wrapper'></div>");

Comment: That works fine, but how do I apply a new class to the resultant dynamic image element?

Comment: @Sunny : in the same way keep the reference ..... `var img = $("<img class='user-img' src='" + path + "'/>").appendTo(user); img.addClass('classname')`

Comment: @Sunny : check it via inspect element option in browser

Comment: found it! It was an extremely silly typo in stylesheet link tag in html! thanks a ton!